# What is a physical address and virtual address? and how do they work?

Tags: memory, memory-management, hardware, bus

And by the by, what does "svchost.exe error" imply when "the memory cannot be written because of 0xc000000e failure"?

Thanks as usual!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A physical address points to a specific place in a specific RAM chip. A virtual address is what most code sees nowadays, allowing the code to not be tied directly to specific locations in RAM. This use of *virtual memory* lets parts of programs and their data be stored on disk when not in use, then brought back into RAM when needed. When it is brought back into RAM, being virtual means that it can be put any place there's space for it rather than having to go back exactly where it came from.

The **0xc000000e** error most likely means that there was a disk failure trying to access some of that virtual memory.

Comment: As an additional point: you have to have support of virtual memory in your hardware (you need MMU [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit)) and in your operating system